# Query optimization in SqlServerCe Compact Edition

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm using SqlserverCe compact edition in my application.
I'm using the left join in query.
Sqlce taking more time to execute.
below is code

```
SELECT calllog.consolename AS consolename, 
       COUNT(consolename)  AS totalcalls, 
       sub.cnt             AS emergencycalls 
FROM   calllog 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT consolename, 
                         COUNT(*) AS cnt 
                  FROM   calllog 
                  WHERE  emergencycall = 'False' 
                         AND ( begintime >= '3/6/2011 10:52:39 AM' 
                               AND endtime <= '10/25/2011 6:52:39 PM' ) 
                  GROUP  BY consolename) AS sub 
         ON calllog.consolename = sub.consolename 
WHERE  ( begintime >= '3/6/2011 10:52:39 AM' 
         AND endtime <= '10/25/2011 6:52:39 PM' ) 
GROUP  BY calllog.consolename, 
          sub.cnt 
ORDER  BY totalcalls ASC
```

please help me how can I avoid the complexty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have an index for BeginTime, EndTime, EmergencyCall, etc.

Comment: I dont have index on any column. will indexes improve performance in this case

Comment: Yes. Indexes improve performance. Without them SQL must look at every row to decide whether to include it.